# My MainViewController is getting big. How can I divide it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, delegates

I am using XCode 4.0.2 for a iOS4 (iPhone) project with a great number (40) FieldText and other objects (a slider for example).

I have a MainViewController.h and a MainViewController.m among other things (AppDelegate, FlipsideViewController, custom classes, etc).

Now the MainViewController.m is getting big (1700 rows). How can I divide this in two o three files? Perhaps moving some delegate methods in a new file? Or something else?

Thank you.

Mauro

Answer (score 1):

Delegate methods are good candidates to be factored out.

You could also try some general refactoring techniques, e.g., if you identify functionality that seems likely to be reused in other classes that could guide your redesign.

Anyway, without seeing the code is really difficult to come up with more concrete suggestions.

Comment: MainViewController has 400 rows of IBActions (button pressed, slide changed, show info and so on). Then 600 rows of TextField delegate methods (textFieldShouldReturn, textFieldDidEndEditing, etc). Then custom methods acting on Text Fields.

Comment: hey, it seems to me that you have a very good redesign at hand if you put all the delegates in their own classes; maybe it could help thinking of controls as "components" that could be moved around together with their delegates (I mean: IB object + delegate. e.g.) to further drive your decisions. Could the custom methods for text fields end up in a category of `UITextField`?

Comment: Text Field contains numbers (double) and custom methods are computation with this numbers.